# Spark Dataframe: Select distinct rows

Tags: java, sql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried two ways to find distinct rows from parquet but it doesn't seem to work.
**Attemp 1:**
`Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.read().parquet("location.parquet").distinct();`

But throws

```
Cannot have map type columns in DataFrame which calls set operations
(intersect, except, etc.), 
but the type of column canvasHashes is map<string,string>;;
```

**Attemp 2:**
Tried running sql queries:

```
Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.read().parquet("location.parquet");
    rawLandingDS.createOrReplaceTempView("df");
    Dataset<Row> landingDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT distinct on timestamp * from df");
```

error I get:

```
= SQL ==
SELECT distinct on timestamp * from df
-----------------------------^^^
```

Is there a way to get distinct records while reading parquet files? Any read option I can use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you face is explicitly stated in the exception message - because `MapType` columns are neither hashable nor orderable cannot be used as a part of grouping or partitioning expression.

Your take on SQL solution is not logically equivalent to `distinct` on `Dataset`. If you want to deduplicate data based on a set of compatible columns you should use `dropDuplicates`:

```scala
df.dropDuplicates("timestamp")
```

which would be equivalent to

```sql
SELECT timestamp, first(c1) AS c1, first(c2) AS c2,  ..., first(cn) AS cn,
       first(canvasHashes) AS canvasHashes
FROM df GROUP BY timestamp
```

Unfortunately if your goal is actual `DISTINCT` it won't be so easy. On possible solution is to leverage Scala* `Map` hashing. You could define *Scala* `udf` like this:

```scala
spark.udf.register("scalaHash", (x: Map[String, String]) => x.##)
```

and then use it in your Java code to derive column that can be used to `dropDuplicates`:

```scala
 df
  .selectExpr("*", "scalaHash(canvasHashes) AS hash_of_canvas_hashes")
  .dropDuplicates(
    // All columns excluding canvasHashes / hash_of_canvas_hashes
    "timestamp",  "c1", "c2", ..., "cn" 
    // Hash used as surrogate of canvasHashes
    "hash_of_canvas_hashes"         
  )
```

with SQL equivalent

```sql
SELECT 
  timestamp, c1, c2, ..., cn,   -- All columns excluding canvasHashes
  first(canvasHashes) AS canvasHashes
FROM df GROUP BY
  timestamp, c1, c2, ..., cn    -- All columns excluding canvasHashes
```

---

* Please note that `java.util.Map` with its `hashCode` won't work, as `hashCode` is not consistent.

Answer (score 4):

1)   If you want to distinct based on coluns you can use it

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array((1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 6))).toDF("no", "age")


scala> df.show
+---+---+
| no|age|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
|  1|  6|
+---+---+

val distinctValuesDF = df.select(df("no")).distinct

scala> distinctValuesDF.show
+---+
| no|
+---+
|  1|
|  3|
+---+
```

2) If you have want unique on all column use dropduplicate

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Array((1, 2), (3, 4),(3, 4), (1, 6))).toDF("no", "age")



scala> df.show

+---+---+
| no|age|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
|  3|  4|
|  1|  6|
+---+---+


scala> df.dropDuplicates().show()
+---+---+
| no|age|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
|  1|  6|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the syntax is incorrect, it should be:

```
Dataset<Row> landingDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT distinct * from df");
```