# In Spark 3.0, how would you use sql to remove duplicates from a specific column? From my understanding, distinct is not supported

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working in Spark 3.0 and I have the below sql query which results in an output of 188 rows (pictured below).  If it matters, fly4 is a TempView:

> SELECT kv.ident, kv.speed, kv.alt FROM fly4
>
> WHERE kv.alt >30000 AND kv.lat IS NOT null AND kv.ident IS NOT null
> AND kv.speed >590
>
> SORT BY kv.ident, kv.speed DESC

[output from above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkLH8.png)

**I would like to add something that will only return unique idents, the highest speed for each unique ident, and the respective alt for those unique idents (3 columns total: ident, speed, alt). Seems fairly simple in concept but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help or direction is much appreciated!**

Comment: Can you specify what is the output that you want? You can do that using groupby but I just wanted to know the output that you are expecting

Comment: Use `dropDuplicates()`. An answer that demonstrates its usage is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011692/2096986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a group by and aggregation to remove duplicates and get the highest speed:

```
SELECT
    kv.ident,
    max(struct(kv.speed as speed, kv.alt as alt))['speed'] as speed, 
    max(struct(kv.speed as speed, kv.alt as alt))['alt'] as alt
FROM fly4
WHERE kv.alt >30000 AND kv.lat IS NOT null AND kv.ident IS NOT null AND kv.speed >590
GROUP BY kv.ident
SORT BY kv.ident, speed DESC
```

Comment: the first block gives me almost exactly what I want except for the altitude field as a column (and get errors when adding it to the SELECT). I want to make sure I understand correctly, are all the changes from the first to the second block of code just to get alt to be included in the output? Not sure if I had to change anything from your code but when pasting the second block in, I am getting the alt column back but just null for all values. Am I missing something? Thanks so much for your help - I'm very new to this if it isn't obvious